# You cannot separate kinematics and dynamics in general relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity

So my lecturer used to say "you cannot separate kinematics and dynamics in general relativity". Can someone make this statement more accessible (and precise) with an example or otherwise?

Like from Newton's laws of motion which basically goes like:

1. An object at rest remains at rest
2. A body in motion remains in motion until a force acts on it.
3. Every action has an equal and opposite reaction.

This enables the distinction of kinematics and dynamics.
I think Einsteins version of 2:

2. An object undergoes geodesic motion in the absence fields and object undergoes geodesic motion.

(I don't wish to digress and make reformulations of 1 and 3)

I don't see why this isn't sufficient to reinstate the seperation of kinematics and dynamics?

Comment: Did you ask your lecturer what he meant? I don't know how Newton's laws are supposed to make that distinction in the presence of classical gravity? In the weak field case absolutely nothing changes between the classical Newtonian approximation of gravity and the GR version with the exception of small corrections. In the solar system these are on the order of 1e-8, if I remember correctly. How are these corrections supposed to distinguish kinematics and dynamics?

Comment: I've seen similar claims in a perimeter institute lecture. I'll dig it up in a while.

Comment: That would be interesting. I am not sure this idea is well thought out, though. The major structural distinction between Newtonian physics and GR is the equivalence principle, which does not get exploited in Newton. If we did, then we should be able to rewrite gravity as a geometric effect in Newton just as well. Even then the only physical distinction between the two theories is given by experiments: Newtonian gravity (even with finite speed of propagation) predicts the motion in the solar system wrong. GR predicts correctly. That is certainly not a function of how a physicist calls things.

Comment: @FlatterMann i had a look there is some talk of kinematics and dynamics in rafel sorkins lectures. But he doesnt make this claim (atleast explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your lecturer's statement is referring to:
the metric tensor appears in Einstein's Equation $$R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab}=\kappa T_{ab}$$
in two ways

- kinematically, since the metric determines the spacetime geometry.
  Thus, the tensors one writes down, including the stress-tensor $T_{ab}$,
  depend on the metric.
  *(Spacetime (via the metric and its curvature) tells matter how to move... a variant of part of a quote by John Wheeler)*
  However, this spacetime geometry is not a background arena as it is in special relativity..
- dynamically, since the metric (thought of like a gravitational potential) is determined by the field equations.
  *(Matter (via the stress tensor) tells spacetime how to curve... a variant of the rest of that quote.)*